# Overleaf Project Coying

Tags: overleaf

I copied a previous project from 2018 in overleaf, yet compilation of the documents gives different results. In the new document, the margins and tables are all shifted, and the spacing is extremely off. The only differences in errors that I can see is that in the new copied project I get an error with remreset is obselete. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Probably better to contact overleaf support directly

Comment: In September 2019 Overleaf switched to a newer TeX live system (see https://www.overleaf.com/blog/tex-live-upgrade-september-2019) new projects and I believe also new clones of older projects will use the newer TeX system, where many packages and classes were updated. While TeX has a reputation for being stable, small changes are not too uncommon if the system is updated after a long time. Not knowing details about your document and the exact nature of the changes, I can't say anything useful for your specific case, though.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) Hi Daniel, moewe already nailed it with the reasoning. If for whatever reason you can't update the copy of the project to work with current TeX Live 2018 packages, contact us at support@overleaf.com with your new project's URL and we can change it back to use our previous TeX Live version manually.

Comment: The changes to the output don't mean much if you have an error. Anything after the first error is liable to be all over the place. When you say a *difference* in errors, do you mean *both* gave errors? I'm guessing you mean just the second. You should fix the errors before doing anything else. If the output still looks different when you've got rid of the errors, then it is worth thinking about why.